# "some" vs "about"

Tags: indefinite-article, numbers

All examples are mine.
Could you help me to deal with them?

**(1a)** *There are **some** thousand people*. - as far as I know, it's correct
**(1b)** *There are **some a** thousand people*. - **???** (I don't know if it's correct)
**(1c)** *There are **some one** thousand people*. - as far as I know, it's correct

**(2a)** *There are **about** thousand people*. - **???** (I don't know if it's correct)
**(2b)** *There are **about a** thousand people*. - I'm sure it's correct
**(2c)** *There are **about one** thousand people*. - I'm sure it's correct

Comment: (1b) and (2a) are incorrect.

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you're just asking for your examples to be checked, that is off-topic. Your title suggests you're considering the difference between the two words but you don't actually ask that in the body of your question.

Comment: I see a clear point of uncertainty and define grammar point here, so I don't see this question as problem

Comment: It would be useful if the OP explained what they think the examples mean or what they are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

"about" is the normal way to express approximate values.  Use this, but you do need "a" or "one", so 2a is not correct.

Using some as an adverb like this is rather rare and informal, 1a and 1c  are rare, but correct.

Comment: As a BrE speaker I don't find anything unusual about _some thousand people_. Oxford Languages gives as its third definition _(used with a number) approximately - 'some thirty different languages are spoken'._

Comment: I've removed the bit about dialect.  Using "some" is still not the most usual way to indicate approximations.